# Where to get coffee in Zurich

Tags: beans, paper-filter

Does anyone know where I can buy delicious coffee beans in Zurich. I just moved here and I am clueless.

I use paper filter ie Moccamaster.

In the UK I used to get Grumpy Mule. It’s actually not high end expensive but it’s delicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several cafés which serve and roasters of specialty coffee in Zurich. These include:

#### Cafés

1. [MAME](https://mame.coffee/) The owners Emi Fukahori and Mathieu Theis have won several prizes in competitions, Emi won the Brewer's Cup in 2018. They roast their own coffee and sell it in both of their stores.
2. [Miró](https://mirocoffee.co/) They roast their coffee in their café and sell it there and online.
3. [Just Coffee](https://www.just-coffee.ch) A small, take-away only café. They serve and sell coffee from roasters all over the world, including Tim Wendelboe. Bring your own cup!
4. [Bean Bank](https://www.instagram.com/beanbankcoffee/) They serve and sell coffee from roasters around the world and are located pretty centrally next to the main station. They are a little pricey though.
5. [COFFEE](http://coffeezurich.com/) They serve coffee from Stoll exclusively.

Friendly people work in all of those cafés and they are more than willing to help you find your ideal cup of coffee or answer any questions you might have.

### Roasters

1. Mame
2. Miró
3. [Stoll](https://www.stoll-kaffee.ch/shop/kaffee/) Really old roastery, they make classic italian roast espresso, organic coffee and specialty coffee.

Other than those, you can find more info on [European Coffee Trip's website](https://europeancoffeetrip.com/zurich/). If you want to order coffee online you also might want to check out [vertical](https://www.vertical.coffee/), [Birchbach](https://www.birchbach.coffee/), [Kaffeemacher](https://shop.kaffeemacher.ch/collections/kaffee) and [Henauer](https://www.p14.ch/).